# setting empty value for first dinamic selector options

Tags: reactjs

I need help to always leave the first value of the dynamic selector empty, so that I can select it, but as I do this automatic update, the value of the first item in the list always comes.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function CreateSelector({ items }) {
  const [firstOption, setFirstOption] = useState();
  const [secondOptionList, setSecondOptionList] = useState([""]);
  const [secondOption, setSecondOption] = useState("NoRoot");
  const [readDfKey, setReadDfKey] = useState();

  function changeSecondDropdown(e) {
    setFirstOption(e.target.value);
    setSecondOptionList(() => [...items[e.target.value]]);
  }
  function updateDfLabel(e) {
    setSecondOption(e.target.value);
  }

  function updateDf() {
    setReadDfKey(`${firstOption}_${secondOption}`);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        className="spotSelector"
        onChange={changeSecondDropdown}
        name="spotSelector"
        id="spotSelector"
      >
        {Object.keys(items).map((item, key) => (
          <option key={key} value={item}>
            {item}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <select
        onChange={updateDfLabel}
        className="spotSelector"
        name="spotRoot"
        id="spotRoot"
      >
        {secondOptionList.map((e, key) => (
          <option key={key} value={e}>
            {e}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <button onClick={updateDf} className="btnSpotSelector">
        Search
      </button>
      <div>
        <h1>{readDfKey}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateSelector;
```

I worked hard to understand react and be able to do this, but whenever I click on the button if I haven't touched the second selector it doesn't work, below is a video of the problem.
appreciate

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a void option before doing the mapping, so that will ensure your first option will be an empty option.

```
 <select
    className="spotSelector"
    onChange={changeSecondDropdown}
    name="spotSelector"
    id="spotSelector"
  >
    <option value = ""> </option>
    {Object.keys(items).map((item, key) => (
      <option key={key} value={item}>
        {item}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
```

It is not the best solution probably but I think it will work.

Comment: First, thank you.
your solution only works for the first interaction, then the same problem comes back.

https://i.imgur.com/zcop6Oi.gif